# Remove directory from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google picked up my development site. It was located at http://orangutan.org/OFI. How do I change it so that orangutan.org/OFI and all the subdirectories under it get redirected to the same place but without the /OFI/ part. This `RewriteRule ^OFI((?:(?:\s*|/.*)$)) $1 [L,R=301,QSA]` works  except it only goes one directory deep. This URL goes to a 404 page for example: orangutan.org/OFI/about/dr-birute-mary-galdikas/

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/OFI/(.*)|/OFI)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2 [L,R=302]
```

It will redirect `orangutan.org/OFI` to `orangutan.org/`, and `orangutan.org/OFI/about/dr-birute-mary-galdikas/` to `orangutan.org/about/dr-birute-mary-galdikas/`.

I saw that you are using 301 redirect - don't do this when you are not sure, that your redirect is working. Always use 302 for testing, because browser will not cache 302 redirects. Probably you need to clear the browser cache before trying the htaccess which I posted here, because your browser will most certainly have your rewrite rule cached.